# Как производить валидацию входящих данных в YII2 для REST API?

Tags: yii2

Как производить валидацию входящих данных в YII2 для REST API?

Вот как это делается не в REST API:

**Controller**

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\Index__GET;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
 
      public function actionIndex($ch_name_url = null)
      {
        $model = new Index__GET();
        $model->ch_name_url = $ch_name_url;

           if($model->validate()){ 
               return $this->render('index');
           }   

      }
}
```

**Model**

```
<?php
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;


class Index__GET extends Model
{

    public $ch_name_url;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['ch_name_url', 'trim'],


            ['ch_name_url', 'required'],

        ];
    }
}
```

И теперь в моделе происходит проверка если вызвать её в контроллере `$model->validate()`. А как проверять входящие данные в REST API, используя при этом `yii\rest\Controller` и `yii\rest\ActiveController`?

Comment: Все точно также. В рестах можно делать такие же свои экшены. Но вам надо в срочном порядке сменить учителя или уйти с этого проекта. Либо почитайте PSR.

Comment: @fedornabilkin Благодарю! А что не так? Модель неправильно именована `Index__GET`? Лишние пробелы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В более менее крупных проектах коробочного варианта реста не хватает, поэтому сразу от него отказываются и делают свои экшены. Вот, например рестовый экшн для добавления товара к заказу.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $params = App::request()->bodyParams;
    $order = OrderService::findModel($params['orderId']);

    // Если не доставка и статус заказа не Изменен, то запрещаем добавление товара
    if (!$order->delivery || !$order->orderStatus()->canAddProduct()) {
        throw ExceptionFactory::actionDenied();
    }
    
    $orderProduct = new OrderProduct();
    
    // загрузка данных в модель и сохранение с валидацией
    if (!$orderProduct->load($params, '') || !$orderProduct->save()) {
        throw ExceptionFactory::incorrectData();
    }

    $this->createEventCallback($order);

    return $orderProduct;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю! Вот это похоже на разумную концепцию. Но почему Вы не проверяете входящие данные? `$params['orderId']`

Comment: Да, тут косяк, надо проверку делать дополнительно.

Comment: Спасибо! Вы имеете в виду проверку в качестве модели, такой, как обычно эта делается через `yii\base\Model`?

Comment: isset($params['orderId']) я про эту.

Comment: Благодарю! Но, разве Вы не считаете нужным проверять входящие данные на сервер, которые взаимодействуют с базой-данных?

Comment: Так валидация же в моделях. Там все проверки.